# setInterval function using innerHTML not updating

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval, innerhtml

I just can't seem to wrap my head around why this will not update what is displayed in the output. I've made a jsfiddle for anyone to look at.

http://jsfiddle.net/sQrn7/

and here's the code:

```
function getPrices(basePrice){
    var dogeValue = 0.005343614; //When changed the output should change.
    var postage = 0.49/dogeValue;
    var sellAmount = (basePrice/dogeValue - postage) - (basePrice*0.1/dogeValue);
    rounded = Math.round(sellAmount);
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = rounded;
}
var timer = setInterval(function() { getPrices(10) }, 1000);
```

Original/complete code:

```
<html>
<script>
var rounded = 0;
    function getPrices(basePrice){
        var dogeValue = <?php echo(file_get_contents("https://www.dogeapi.com/wow/?a=get_current_price")); ?>;
        var postage = 0.49/dogeValue;
        var sellAmount = (basePrice/dogeValue - postage) - (basePrice*0.1/dogeValue);
        rounded = Math.round(sellAmount);
        document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = rounded;
    }
    var timer = setInterval(function() { getPrices(10) }, 1000);
</script>
<body onload="getPrices(10);">
    <div id="txt"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you tell us how the output is supposed to evolve along the time?

Comment: Sure, you can see the "Original/complete code" edit I made and look at where I defined dogeValue. That PHP code gets the value from that website which changes every few minutes.

Comment: Alright, now this is clear : the PHP part is executed only once on page load :D

Comment: Hmm, okay so that is my problem. despite being in a function that is supposed to be repeated the php is only called once for some strange reason. Any ideas on how to fix this??

Comment: This is not so strange :) Javascript and PHP are executed in separated contexts : PHP > server side, Javascript > client side.

Comment: AHH, because it is php in the middle of js... ahhhh THANK YOU! but now... I have no idea where to go from here, I guess I could do something similar in php that fetches the value every minute and assigns it to a variable that I could echo into the dogeValue section? maybe? I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

and Edit: I knew AJAX would be the way to do this but I tried to stay away from it because I've never used it. Guess this is a good time to start.

Comment: You can't live without Ajax today ;) Have fun!

Comment: Using Ajax from scratch can be painful, I suggest you to use a library. I'd like to avoid [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you only need the Ajax part but I'm not familiar with other javascript libraries. This website might help hopefully (I've never used it) : http://microjs.com/#ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP part is executed only once on page load. Take a look at the source code (right click on the page, "show source code"), you'll see the value assigned statically, since it's generated with PHP before the page is loaded into the browser. Keep in mind that Javascript and PHP are executed in separated contexts : PHP > server side, Javascript > client side.

A little help to resolve your problem : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the console, it will say `Uncaught ReferenceError: sellAmount is not defined`

The reason: you are missing space at the definition of the variable `sellAmount`: you wrote `varsellAmount = ...`

**Use this, and it will work:**

```
function getPrices(basePrice){
    var dogeValue = 0.005343614; //When changed the output should change.
    var postage = 0.49/dogeValue;
    var sellAmount = (basePrice/dogeValue - postage) - (basePrice*0.1/dogeValue);
    var rounded = Math.round(sellAmount);
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = rounded;
}
var timer = setInterval(function() { getPrices(10) }, 1000);
```

See your updated feedle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sQrn7/

**EDIT:** after your edited Question, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ne2gN/

The output is always the same, because the value of the dogeValue always stays the same. You have to change the value, in order to see a change in the output.

This is the new code:

```
var dogeValue = 0.005343614; //When changed the output should change.
function getPrices(basePrice){

    var postage = 0.49/dogeValue;
    var sellAmount = (basePrice/dogeValue - postage) - (basePrice*0.1/dogeValue);
    var rounded = Math.round(sellAmount);
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = rounded;
    dogeValue+=0.1;
}
var timer = setInterval(function() { getPrices(10) }, 1000);
```

**Edit 2:** After your question-edit, the answer stays the same - you can still define it globally:

```
<html>
<script>
var rounded = 0;
var dogeValue = <?php echo(file_get_contents("https://www.dogeapi.com/wow/?a=get_current_price")); ?>;

    function getPrices(basePrice){        
        var postage = 0.49/dogeValue;
        var sellAmount = (basePrice/dogeValue - postage) - (basePrice*0.1/dogeValue);
        rounded = Math.round(sellAmount);
        document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = rounded;
        dogeValue+=0.1; //change it
    }
    var timer = setInterval(function() { getPrices(10) }, 1000);
</script>
<body onload="getPrices(10);">
    <div id="txt"></div>
</body>
```

You can place your php-Tags everywhere in your code - it doesn't matter if they are inside our outside a function. This code does exacly the same as yours, with the only difference, that `getPrices()` is now able to change the `dogeValue`.

Comment: Unfortunately I wish it was that simple. Must have been a formatting error I made when I copied my code over. I also accidentally supplied the wrong jsfiddle. My original post has been updated. When you edit the value of dogeValue the the number should change in the result panel.

Comment: It does change - if you change the value inside your code. The variable itself always has the same value, it never gets changed.

Comment: By change I mean without re-running the code. That is why I have
`var timer = setInterval(function() { getPrices(10) }, 1000);`
at the bottom, It should run the function every second, and with a changed value should write a different result.

Comment: But where do you change your value? In my second example, I don't rerun the code. Everytime the setInterval fires, the number changes.

Comment: Hmmm, I've been looking at your edit for a while now and still do not understand why I must declare dogeValue outside of the function, I need it inside the function because instead of assigning it to a constant number I've assigned it to some embedded PHP code that echos the value from: https://www.dogeapi.com/wow/?a=get_current_price

Therefore I need for every time my function is ran dogeValue gets a new assignment since the number on that website changes.

Comment: You have to declare it globally, and it will be avaible everywhere in your code. Also inside your function. If you declare it inside your function, each time you execute it, the variable will be generated, and gets the same value asigned. I declared it outside, otherwise I wouldn't be able to change the value permament.

Comment: I can now see your purpose for declaring it globally but in my case I'm doing this: see edit in original post. I suppose I should have posted my complete code to begin with. If you look at where I declare dogeValue you'll see why I need it re-assigned every time the function is ran as the number on that webpage changes. my apologies.